# Why do all the directories on my tablet have all these weird numbers?

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-tab

I have a Samsung Galaxy 10.1, running Android 3.2, which I've rooted.

When I plug it in by USB to my Ubuntu computer, it looks like this:

[image]

There's about 24 or so directories, all numbered as shown in the image. As far as I can tell, they don't correspond to any directories actually on the device, and I can neither find any files I think should be on the device or transfer any files to the device. *(To be accurate: I can copy files to one of the weirdly numbered directories, but then I can't find them if I try to look for them from the tablet interface.)*

What's going on, and, more importantly, how do I get a normal connection to my tablet so I can transfer files back and forth?

**Update 1:** I have learned this is probably "MTP mode". I can't seem to find any option to disable or change it.

**Update 2:** I have tried turning "USB debugging" both on and off, and neither way seems to make a difference.

**Update 3:** I've [asked about this issue also on the Ubuntu SE site](https://askubuntu.com/q/122443/17041), in case part of my problem is on the Ubuntu side.

**Update 4:** Here's another error message I get if I try to use mtpfs to connect to the Android device:

[image]

Comment: Voting to close as this has been rendered moot by upgrading the tablet to Android 4.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're connecting the tab in Media Player (MTP) mode. Try switching it to Camera mode, it usually gives better results. If I remember correctly, this option can be found in `Settings -> Storage -> Menu button (top right) -> USB computer connection`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. However, there is no menu button at all under storage. There's just a bar graph showing me the device's storage memory usage. And I might be blind to the obvious, but I can't find any "USB Connection mode" option anywhere in the settings interface.

Comment: Hmm, I was almost sure it was there. Now I'm running ICS so I can't check. Then your best bet would be to try gMtp, here's some instructions: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=13755464&postcount=1

Comment: Hey, can you find the menu `Settings -> Wireless and networks -> USB Settings`? This might solve your problem.

Comment: There's no `Settings -> Wireless and networks -> USB Settings` either, I'm afraid. The only USB setting that I have found anywhere in the settings is `Applications->Development->USB debugging`. As mentioned in the question, it has no impact on this issue.

Comment: Also, I tried to install gmtp as you recommended in a comment above, and I got through the whole process, but when I actually attempt to connect to my device through the gmtp interface, it hangs.

Comment: @DaveMG I'm running CM9 (Android 4.0.3) on the GT 10.1 and I definitely have that menu button at exactly the place onik mentioned. Are you sure you checked the *top right* of the screen? It's a bit nondescript.

Comment: @hheimbuerger: I'm not running 4.0.3. I'm running 3.2. I wanted to run ICS on my Galaxy Tab, but apparently there isn't support for the camera yet.

Answer (score -3):

Most likely hidden directories used by Android to store hidden data, that are shown/visible when you connect it to your computer.

Try using root explorer on your tablet to see the directories.