# Can I disable MTP mode and just have a regular USB connection?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, usb-connection-mode

I have a Galaxy Tab 10.1, and it's been rooted.

Whenever I try to connect it by USB, it goes into MTP mode, [which isn't working for me](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/21730/5892) when connecting to my Ubuntu Linux computer.

I'd really rather not have to deal with some software to make transfers. I'd rather just have it show up as a USB exernal drive like my phone does.

Is there a way I can disable MTP and make my tablet just show up as a USB external drive?

Comment: Adding this so that the questions are linked, not a direct answer to your question but goes through other options that could be used: [Better way to connect Galaxy Nexus (ICS) to Linux](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15877)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure. But IIRC, the problem with normal USB storage is Android has to partition your phone for internal storage and USB storage. Your computer can then umount the USB storage from phone and mount it in your computer. So in many phones without MTP, even though the internal storage had capacity like 16GB, only 1 or 2 GB was available for app installation. While some phone gave up to 8GB for app, that space was wasted for people who didn't need that much for app but needed space for music and photos.

With MTP mode, there isn't separate partition but a whole single partition. So if you have 16GB internal storage in your phone, you can use whole 16GB for apps, music and photos.

MTP mode is available from Honeycomb and I don't think it's an optional component. I mean I don't think you can say I don't want MTP mode, I want USB storage mode.

Comment: Okay, so I need to forget about trying to not have MTP and instead focus on how to make it work on Ubuntu. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The galaxy nexus has this same storage configuration as the tab.  Perhaps this will work for you in Ubuntu as well.  http://rootzwiki.com/topic/12524-how-to-mount-your-galaxy-nexus-in-linux-ubuntu/

Comment: Well, is there any way to switch it between MTP and USB...? Because using MTP is a lot slower than USB as far as I experienced it.

Answer (score 0):

No other way for disabling MTP Mode, except you have Android generic smartphone such as local manufacturer smartphone.